# Data array changes in knockout are not getting reflected to UI?

Tags: javascript, html, web, knockout.js

AM working on a simple knockout application. Am able to do a successfull binding of data to the view layer. Howsoever on changing the data array for a button click event the values are not getting reflected on to the view layer.

Following is my code:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>   
<script src="knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
/*Sample data array that will have the changing values*/
var sampledata = [{ title1:"abc",title2:"abc2" },
{title1:"def",title2:"ghi"}];

/*View model that is used for binding*/
function sampleViewModel() {
var self=this;
self.sampledata2 = ko.observableArray(sampledata);
}

var my = { viewModel: new sampleViewModel() };

/*Applying bindings using knockout*/
function initialize() {       
   ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
}

/*Changing values for the onclick of the button*/
function changevalues(){
my.viewModel.sampledata2([{ title1:"zzz1",title2:"yyy1" }, {title1:"zzz2",title2:"yyy2"}]);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>


                <div id="frame" data-bind="foreach: sampledata">


                    <!-- Displays the "title" field. -->
                    <h4 id="duration" data-bind="text: title1"></h4>
                    <h4 id="time" data-bind="text: title2"></h4>

                </div>
                <button id="clickme">Click me to change the data values</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click',changevalues,false);

initialize();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how I can change the value of that data array for the button click event. I know this has something to do with ko.observableArray(). But I have a doubt that am complicating the actual logic. Would be great if someone can provide a solution on the same.

Comment: please don't use `<!-- -->` inside `<script>...</script>`, use `/* comment */` or `// comment` for javascript comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make self.sampledata2 an observable array.

```
self.sampledata2 = ko.observableArray(sampledata);
```

You need to store the view model in a variable (let's say viewModel), and then update it as follows:

```
viewModel.sampledata2([{ title1:"zzz1",title2:"yyy1" }, {title1:"zzz2",title2:"yyy2"}]);
```

Do not change sampledata directly.

Comment: I took your idea of storing the viewModel in a variable and accessing it. I have also made the relative changes to my existing script in the question. 
   
Still I couldn't reflect the values to get it updated to my view layer. Please check the question for the updated script and let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: It seems to be right to me. You need just update your html data-bind, so that it uses foreach: sampledata2 instead of sampledata.